# How do I update my Data-Tier Application project to reflect schema changes made in other tools?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, data-tier-applications

I created a data tier application project and imported the initial db schema. How do I update this project when a DBA makes a change to the db schema using SSMS? I want to re-import the database into the project again.

This is also relevant in projects where I use Entity Framework to drop and recreate the database on my development sql server. I then want to re-import the schema into the DAC project, and then deploy those changes to staging and production sql servers as a dacpac.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/b9de7c54-2fc1-439b-b6b9-08ce8fd42555 and ignore the first few responses.  I personally find this limiation annoying